# Returning Mat object in Java in OpenCV 3.2

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, mat

I'm trying to build a Java Class for implementing LSB Image Steganography.

I'm using OpenCV 3.2 for this.

I wrote the encoding logic in the method `encodeImage(String message)` of class `LSBImageStego`,which would take the secret message and encode it in the given cover Image(The cover image will be taken by Constructor).

I'm able to modify the Pixel values by channging LSB bits(I'm changing LSB bits of only a single channel).I'm using `MatObj.put(row,col,data)` to write back the new Pixel values.I tried to Print those new Pixel values after `put()` and the Pixel values were changed successfully.

I'm returning the CoverImage(as I have made changes by encoding message) and Saving the image by `imwrite()` .

Now,when I try to decode the EncodedImage , I found that the Image had the Old Pixel values but not the Encoded Pixel Values.This indicates that,though I wrote the EncodedPixel Values using `put()` in `encodeImage(String message)` ,the `Mat` object was not being returned.

Here is the code for `encodeImage(String message)` of class `LSBImageStego`

```
/**
getBeautifiedBinaryString()

Returns a binary string of length 8 by taking a number.
This function is working perfectly.

 */
/**
binaryStringMessage

is a private String in the class & contains the Binary form of the Secret Message.
 */


/**
    This function takes Secret Message and replaces 2 bits from LSB(First Channel of Image)
    with the bits of Message
 */
public Mat encodeImage(String message){

/**
        //coverImage is a Mat Object & following is the code in constructor of a class
        this.coverImage = coverImage;
        this.coverImage_rows = (int)coverImage.size().height;
        this.coverImage_cols = (int)coverImage.size().width;


*/
        System.out.println("Number of Rows : " + this.coverImage_rows);
        System.out.println("Number of Columns : " + this.coverImage_cols);

//      This is used as a pointer in the BinaryString ,so that,it can be embedded easily
        int messageStringCounter = 0;
        for(int rowCount = 0 ; rowCount <= this.coverImage_rows -1 ; rowCount++){
            for(int colCount = 0; colCount <= this.coverImage_cols -1 ; colCount++){
                try{

                    if(messageStringCounter > this.binaryStringMessage.length() - 2 ){
                        System.out.println("RETURNING pic");
                        return this.coverImage;
                    }
                    String newLSBBits = this.binaryStringMessage.substring(messageStringCounter , messageStringCounter+2);
                    System.out.println(">> "+messageStringCounter + " >> " + newLSBBits);
                    messageStringCounter+=2;
                    System.out.println("ORIGINAL : "+this.getBeautifiedBinaryString(this.coverImage.get(rowCount , colCount)[0]));
                    String modifiedBinaryString = this.getBeautifiedBinaryString(this.coverImage.get(rowCount , colCount)[0]).substring(0 , this.getBeautifiedBinaryString(this.coverImage.get(rowCount , colCount)[0]).length() - 2) + newLSBBits;
                    System.out.println("MODIFIED : " + modifiedBinaryString);
                    double[] data = new double[3];
                    data[0] = Integer.parseInt(modifiedBinaryString , 2);
                    data[1] = this.coverImage.get(rowCount , colCount)[1];
                    data[2] = this.coverImage.get(rowCount , colCount)[2];

                    // Im checking whether the Pixel values are being changed as expected or not.
                    System.out.println("BEFORE : " + this.coverImage.get(rowCount , colCount)[0]);
                    this.coverImage.put(rowCount , colCount , data);
                    System.out.println("AFTER : " + this.coverImage.get(rowCount , colCount)[0]);
                    // The Pixel values were changed as expected
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Exception Handled");
                }
            }
        }
        return this.coverImage;
}
```

and I'm calling the above method from `main()` in another class,as follows.

```
public class Imple {
    static{
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Imgcodecs imageCodecs = new Imgcodecs();

        Mat mat = imageCodecs.imread("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Desktop\\test.jpg");

        LSBImageStego obj = new LSBImageStego(mat);
        String message = "Hello World";
        if(obj.checkEncodePossibility(message)){
            System.out.println("OK");
        }else{
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
        Mat encodedImage = obj.encodeImage(message).clone();
        imageCodecs.imwrite("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Desktop\\test_ENCODED.jpg" ,encodedImage );


        Mat mat2 = imageCodecs.imread("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Desktop\\test_ENCODED.jpg");

//      While debugging the Below function,I found that the Changed Pixel values were not being written back to the Disk
        obj.decodeImage(mat2);
//         In the above method,as part of debugging,I'm printing the Pixel values to the console.

    }

}
```

I took care of other logics such as the length of binaryString of Message being odd or even etc...

The only problem is with the EncodedImage which I'm saving to Disk,does not contain the Encoded Pixel Values.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're saving the image to jpg, which does lossy compression and messes with your pixels values. Bmp or png should work.

Comment: @Reti43
Yes it worked.Thanks!!!
I'm really stupid these days :)

Answer (score 1):

JPEG does Lossy Compression.So the Encoded Pixel Values will be lost and there is a high probability that,it will be the same old original Pixel value as only LSB of Pixel Intensities are being changed.But,this is not the case with the PNG or Bitmap.

Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) to get more info about JPEG Compression algorithm.